# 'Failed to Execute Script error' after converting .py file to executable

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I'm trying to convert my py file to an executable but after the pyinstaller process , i'm getting the Failed to Execute Script error.

I tried to do it with the auto-py-to-exe app for this and get same error , also tried with the pyinstaller via cmd code and same error again .

Comment: Make sure that all the dependencies are in the same folder as the exe

Comment: Could you please give me some more detail , as i said i'm newbie , thanks for your anwser btw.

Comment: Okay so I think you're using some additional files like `.xlsx` to run your python script, ain't you?

Comment: Yes , I am  using 3 xlsx file for my code

Comment: So if your exe is in a folder say , `C:/Users/you/your_exe` then all those three `.xlsx` file should be in the same directory as of the exe that is `C:/Users/you/`

Comment: Then you need to have those xlsx files in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: They are at the same folder with the exe file , but still same error.

Comment: are you including `tkinter` as a dependency in your pyinstaller script